# Install Docker on Jenkins on OSX

Tags: macos, jenkins, docker

I have a local jenkins on OSX.

It's working fine, but now I want to perform `docker builds` inside the jenkins.

So I have to install docker inside my jenkins.

Is this possible, because I thought you can't install docker on osx? (only docker-machine).

I don't know if it's possible to configure jenkins to use docker-machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker-machine is a Linux VM.

*First option*: start a Jenkins slave inside this VM, it will have access to the docker daemon to build your image.

*Second option*: configure Jenkins to use Docker slaves using Docker-machine. You will be able to build docker images from a docker slave.

I would do this for a PoC or an evaluation setup. For a Production setup, I would use real linux hosts to build Docker images.